# Cpanel email API

Tags: php, cpanel, email

I have a php script that creates email accounts through the cpanel. I am using the xmlapi  to do that. What I am looking to do now is to send,receive,delete emails through xmlapi via php. I searched the web but I have not been able to find documentation on the API to help me figure out how to do it.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: not sure if this is the right approach, how about imap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't do this with cpanel API. cPanel is used to manage email accounts, forwarders,.. but not an inbox. Instead you can do that through an IMAP connection.

See more on [PHP IMAP reference](http://php.net/manual/es/book.imap.php)

Comment: Yup! I realized that after @Dagon's comment! Thanks!